# A successful call to the fseek() function clears the end-of-file indicator for the stream

Tags: c, file, pointers, stdio, fseek

The manual for the standard c library function fseek says: "A successful call to the `fseek()`function clears the end-of-file indicator for the stream."

To me it sounds like saying if `EOF is at 2` and I call `fseek()` to get the pointer at 4, that should work and `eof` will be now pointing to 5. But when I test this hypothesis, the pointer doesn't advance beyond current `EOF`(2 in above case), and hence my understanding of the line is wrong. What does this line mean then? Thanks!

Comment: It means that if you've previously hit EOF and then you fseek to a valid position *within* the file then the EOF flag will no longer be set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remember that the `EOF` flag is not set until you actually try to *read* from beyond the end of the file.

With `fseek` clearing the flag, it does this even if you seek to beyond the end of the file. And it works because the flag will be set again next time you read.

That is why it's a bad idea to have loops such as `while (!feof(...))`, as those will then loop once to many without detecting the actual end of the file condition.

Comment: Thanks! I should have remembered EOF is a flag and not a position in the file. Now it makes sense.